# Is there any effective solution for full-text search in Entity Framework 4 that doesn't rely on Stored Procedures?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-4, full-text-search

I'm looking for a full-text search solution for Entity Framework 4. Stored Procedures cannot be considered because I have the need to compose queries. That is, given a search term I need to do something like this:

```
var query = from p in db.People.FullTextSearch('henry') where p.MaritalStatus == 2 select p;
```

I can't find anything like that. The closer I got is a Sql Server UDF imported in the store scheme combined with a custom EdmFunction. But UDFs in the store scheme cannot return Entity types.

The bottom line is: How can I implement SQL Server Full Text in an effective way that doesn't rely on Stored Procedures?

Comment: *personally*, my view is that it is folly to treat things like EF as an all-encompassing-I-must-use-this-for-everything layer. It is a tool; only a tool. It is OK to use more than one tool. Indeed, even if that tool works for 80% of your needs, you should try to *force* it to do things it can't do well - just use an additional tool that can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer in current EF versions is: no way. EF makes abstraction on most common database features but for more advanced scenarios EF + SQL / Stored procedures are one tool not two tools.